# Getting data from an Unbound Service in Android

Tags: android, service, ipc

I currently I have an unbound service that is running continually grabbing my gps position that I start on boot. I then have an app that is suppose to plot where I've been by pulling data from the service.

I can't bind the the service to talk to it or it will be destroyed once I close the app.

Is there any good way to get data from an unbound service or keep a bound service from dying once I unbind it?

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a workaround for keeping your service alive. Call your service by calling startService and then bind to the service. This way your activity is maintaining the the lifecycle of the service.

Comment: Bt if you just want to get the data  from service, then shared preference should help. Its even better than the callback function.Just put the new gps location in your shared service and the activity could look in to it whenever it needs to.

Comment: Actually that's not the best idea to use shared preferences for communication between activity and service. It's not what preferences were ment to do. And there is at least one problem worth thinking about: how do you trigger the activity to check for new data in the preferences? Every X seconds? That's not a good solution. Sending broadcast from service and registering broadcastreceiver in an activity (and update UI in it) is much better approach.

Answer (score 2):

As the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle) states:

> A service can be both started and have
>   connections bound to it. In such a
>   case, the system will keep the service
>   running as long as either it is
>   started or there are one or more
>   connections

So first, start the service with [startService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29), then bind to it in onResume(), and unbind in onPause(). The service will continue to run nevertheless because it is *started*. And when you want to stop the service either call [stopSelf()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#stopSelf%28%29) from within the service or [stopService()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#stopService%28android.content.Intent%29) from an activity. It will stop right away or as soon as you unbind from it if there's any connection alive.

Comment: you are saying that if i create a bounded service but call it by invoking startService() then the service will continue to run even after onDestroy() if i do not call stopService() or stopSelf()..is my understanding correct?

Comment: will this service not get stopped when activity component is destroyed?